# Favorite 3-player zero-sum-game?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am looking for a $3$-player game that meets the following requirements:

- It should be a zero-sum-game
- It should be simple in the sense that the payoff table is not too large (ideally memorisable by an average human)
- Every Nash Equilibrium involves only mixed strategies

One instance is the $3$-player version of "rock-paper-scissors", see [Mixed Strategy Nash Equilibrium of Rock Paper Scissors with 3 players?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277120/mixed-strategy-nash-equilibrium-of-rock-paper-scissors-with-3-players). Do you have other nice examples?

One could generalized the $3$-player version of "rock-paper-scissors": To any symmetric $2$-player zero-sum-game one can construct a $3$-player in the following way. The options of each player are the same as in the $2$-player game. If the players all play the same or all a different option, then declare a stalemate. If only two different options are played, then we can consider those players that play the same option as one player in the $2$-player game and split the outcome. I call such a $3$-player game induced by a $2$-player game.

Are there nice examples for $3$-player games that meet the above requirements but are not induced by a $2$-player game?

Comment: With three players, there can be mixed Nash equilibria where two players mix while one does not. Does this satisfy your requirement?